# Understanding funeral entry from 1695 in Bödigheim

Tags: church-records, german-language, kurrent, german

I could use some assistance understanding this funeral entry from 1695 Bödigheim.  Generally between Google translate and my very very limited German, I can figure out enough of the entry to get the data I need.  However, in this case, I'm having trouble figuring out the father, the daughter, or the daughter's age at death.

Who died here?

[image]

Transcription: den 21.t. Octobris Ist Obgesetzten Müller Töchterl. welches Sie vor 3. Vierth. jahren gezeuget nachgefolget Und den 22.t. huius zur Erden Christl. gebrauch gemäß bestättiget worden.

Google translation: the 21st. Octobris is the superior Müller's daughter. which you before the 3rd fourth. years conceived, followed and the 22nd. huius to the earth Christl. Use has been confirmed in accordance with.

I have all Müller <s>births</s> baptisms in Bödigheim prior to 1720 in my database; these are the ones born between 1690 and 1695:

[image]

Comment: it seems a bit strange way to describe the death of a newborn baby but "vor dreiviertel Jahren gezeuget" maybe means 9 months from conception, so a daughter is born on 21th Oct, dies and is buried next day

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense than anything else I can think of.  Did you want to enter it as an answer, so you can get the bounty?

Comment: I don't feel I can write a good answer but since you lose these points anyway..

Comment: "obgesetzt" means "mentioned above or previously", perhaps in the record directly above the one cited. Also, the following word is "Mutter" (see the line just above "zur Erden die unser aller Mutter ist bestättiget worden" -- "buried in the earth which is mother to us all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea about "vor 3. Vierth. jahren gezeuget". Assuming it means "conceived nine months ago" (3/4 of a year = 9 months), so it may be a bit strange way to describe the death of a newborn baby.
 Müller's daughter is born on October 21th, dies (possibly immediately and with no time to be baptized) and is buried next day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).